# How to search a string for a char and assign it to another char without knowing the correspondence?

Tags: c++

> The first file will contain exactly two lines that represent a way to encode text. The first line will be a subset of the letters A-Z, and characters on the second line will represent the encoding. The second file will be an encoded text.
>
> Since not all of the letters appear in file1, there may be a letter in the encoded text that you do not know how to decode. This is where the third argument is used. The third argument will be a word that is known to appear in the source text. Your job is to try assigning corresponding letters to the parts of the cipher that are unknown until the word in the third argument appears in the decoded text.
>
> file1:
>
> ```
> ABCFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ
> PDFZATMEBYOCSWINVXLJRUQ
> (empty line)
> ```
>
> file2:
>
> ```
> VTK GHA EXOSKG HLKI VTK ZKCFK
> (empty line)
> ```
>
> `./p1 file1 file2 DOG`
>
> `THE DOG JUMPED OVER THE FENCE`

my code:

```
while(file2.get(c))
{  
    if(ispunct(c) || isdigit(c) || isspace(c))
    {
        cout << c;
    } 
    if(word == "DOG")
    {
        if(c == 'K')
            cout << "E";
    }
    if(word == "BACK")
    {
        if(c == 'A')
            cout << "V";
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++)
    {
        if(c == str2.at(j))
        {
            cout << str1.at(j);
            continue;
        }
        if(word.find(c) && (!(str2.find(c))))
        {
            if(c == str2.at(j))
                continue;

            for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
            {

                if(c != word.at(i))
                {
                    ???
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ???
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }

    }          
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong.  You should not be coding for the example data; instead you should be coding for the generic case.  You may want to use a lookup-array.

Comment: So for example, you read in the encryption string (second line of data). Read in a letter.  Find the letter in the encryption string and save the index.  Use the index on the first string to find the decrypted data.

Comment: What is a look up array?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code fragment that will hopefully help you understand the algorithm.

```
std::string alphabet;
std::string encryption_key;

// Read in the alphabet string.
std::getline(std::cin, alphabet);

// Read in the encryption key.
std::getline(std::cin, encryption_key)
//...
std::string message;
while (std::getline(file2, message))
{
   const unsigned int length = message.length();
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
   {
       // Extract the character, for conversion, from the message.
       const char c = message[i];

       // Search the alphabet for the character.
       // The alphabet contains the characters that are subject to conversion.
       std::string::size_type position = alphabet.find(c);
       if (position == std::string::npos)
       {
           // character is not in alphabet, print it and continue with next char.
           std::cout << c;
           continue;
       }
       else
       {
           // Lookup the character in the encryption key to get the index.
           const unsigned int index = encryption_key.find(c);
           // Convert the character, c, by using the same index into the alphabet.
           const char converted = alphabet[index];
           std::cout << converted;
       }
   }
}
```

You'll need to handle the case where the character is in the alphabet, but not in the encryption key.

**Edit: The diagram**
This task assumes a 1:1 relationship between the alphabet and the encryption key.

```
+---+---+---+---+     +---+  
| A | B | C | D | ... | Z |  
+---+---+---+---+     +---+  
  ^   ^   ^   ^         ^  
  |   |   |   |         |  
  v   v   v   v         v  
+---+---+---+---+     +---+  
| P | D | F | Z | ... | Q |  
+---+---+---+---+     +---+
```

For **decoding**, when you see the letter `P`, you replace it with the letter `A`, replace `D` with `B`, etc.

Comment: So in the if(position == string::npos) is where I would need to see if the corresponding letter is in the third argument so I can convert it? Because not all of the letters are in the first file.

Comment: we run the program like this ./p1 file1 file2 DOG if the letter isn't in the second string of file 1. We're suppose to use the third argument, in this case DOG, to find the missing letters. So G -> D and H -> O in the example above

Comment: If the character is not in File 1 (i.e. the alphabet), you'll need to figure out how to handle this.  So, yes, you can try substituting from the third argument.